# How to highlight certain dates in pickadate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

I am using Alsum pickadate plugin and I don't know how to highlight certain days of the calendar.
Here is my code.

```
<input type="text" id="date-select" class="form-control form-date pickadate" name="date" hidden>

<script src="{{asset('vendors/js/pickers/pickadate/picker.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendors/js/pickers/pickadate/picker.date.js')}}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $input = $(".pickadate").pickadate({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            selectDates: {
                'color':'brown',
                'date': '2020-03-22',
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work at all. I have tried to find the answer but I couldn't.

Comment: Kindly post some more details - Error message or screen capture as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no such 'selectDates' property in pickadate object.
This code would work fine for your script.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $input = $(".pickadate").pickadate({
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                formatSubmit: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                editable: false,
                min: new Date(),
            });

            var picker = $input.pickadate('picker');
            picker.set('highlight',
                    [2020, 2, 29],
            );
        });
    </script>
```